# Lucene search return no records

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am facing a quite strange issue searching with Lucene. I have a query with 3 clauses. If I launch the query with just 2 clauses in share, it returns several documents, included the one I am seeking for. Nevertheless, if I add the third clause to the query and perform the query in **share** it returns no results, but it returns the document I am looking for when I launch it in the alfresco **console**!.

I guess it is not a grant issue since I get the document I am looking for when the query is less restrictive. The query with the third clause just fails for a specific value, for the others it works fine.

It maybe an indexing problem but in that case I think it should fail when launching the query in alfresco console as well.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Querying in Alfresco Share differs from querying in the Nodebrowser or directly through JavaScript.

If you take a look at: alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.lib.js which is a repository webscript triggered by Share. You'll see in the code it fail saves results.

So you'll need to play around to get the right results.

Comment: Hi! I have just found out that the search just work if I use a 3-character clause!!! For example, if it fails for "home", it works for "hom". Any idea???

Comment: I'm sorry come again? why don't you list your actual query in the topic? Just saying clauses doesn't help us figure out the problem :).